# I am trying to get the value of value of textarea on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a textarea element in javascript code and trying to drag the textarea element on the canvas element using mouse events and enter the text into textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at a framework like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) because it has the drag and drop features you want, then use an event listener for the drop event (see line #18 of the referenced page source code) to strokeText() (see [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp)) into the canvas.